# How to push to windows git remote server from a local windows repository

Tags: git, ssh, openssh

My company was using SVN for code versioning now we are going to use GIT so I installed git on my local windows server and made one repository there using git bash commands.

```
$ mkdir iri-repo
$ cd iri-repo/
$ git init --bare
```

In the local windows server, I created a local repository from where I want to push the codes to my remote windows server using git bash. The commands used are

```
$ mkdir project
$ cd project
$ git init 
$ vi mycode
$ git add mycode
$ git commit -m "my first commit" mycode
```

After this to add the remote server to windows local server I used the command

```
$ git remote add origin dpmadministrator@192.168.*.***:/iri-repo
```

But when I am pushing the codes it says "Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists"

```
$ git push origin master
```

I also tried using open-ssh features but still, I am not able to push to my remote server.

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing a mistake or what is the correct way to do this configuration?

Comment: Confusing! Are you using the term "server" for both the remote server and the local client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your Git user account on your Git client, with the account created on  your Git server and the permissions it has, and the `dpmadministrator` account.

In addition you should also check your settings for openssh too.